# JavaScript: How do I convert input that contains commas from a user to a number?

Tags: javascript, string-conversion

When I'm inputting test values, numbers to be specific, into my pay calculation script, it works fine (Ex. 10000). But when I input a test value with a comma (think "10,000" or "$10,000"), the script reads the values up to where the comma would (think "10" instead of "10,000". How would I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var valueFromPrompt = window.prompt(...)
var valueNowANumber = +valueFromPrompt.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');
```

Replace all non-numeric (pattern `/[^\d\.]/g`) with blank. The leading `+` converts the string to a number. Converting a blank string (because there's no number in the raw string) makes it `0`.

Now this won't cover all edge cases for numbers, so you might want to tweak the pattern. You might want to read more about [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions)

Comment: I'll nitpick to point out that this will convert `$10.00` to `1000`, which can be problematic.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question but would append the .replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '') to end of the variable that is holding the value?

Comment: @CaZ yup. like `var isNowANumber = +stringNumber.replace(...)

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer Should I change the way I store the values? (Ex:  monthlySalesStr = window.prompt("Enter the salesperson's monthly sales.", " ");
                    monthlySales = parseFloat(monthlySalesStr);                                  return monthlySales.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');

Comment: @vihan1086: But what we want is "neither a digit nor a dot"

Comment: Inside a `[]` you don't need to escape a dot. So a `[^\d.]` will do just fine